# How to use Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp with tls and self-signed certificate?

Tags: zend-framework, email, smtp, ssl-certificate, ssl

I'm using `SMTP` transport. I would like to use `TLS` but my hosting has self-signed certificate.

It is possible to use `TLS` in such situation?

Comment: Yes it is, just specify you're port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS itself has no concept of the certificate being self signed or not. When you initiate a TLS connection (either by connecting to a specific port or via STARTTLS) the server and client negotiate the TLS connection.

As part of the TLS negotiation it is up to the client and server to decide whether the certificate that they're presented is valid or not. If the certificate is self signed it's possible that the client (I'm assuming you're the server) may reject the certificate because it's not issued by a known CA or it might accept it.

It's therefore possible to use TLS with self signed certificates (we do it) but it's also possible that a client could reject the connection because it cannot verify the certificate. If you full have control of the clients (which you do here) you can of course aid this and ensure you always accept your hosts certificate.